# $block->getChildBlock("")->setData('') not working in loop

Tags: magento2

I have used

```
$block->getChildBlock("")->setData("");
echo $block->getChildHtml('productlist', false);
```

in my phtml file in a for each loop but it only initializa once in a loop and remaining same in whole loop execution. how to setData differently with each loop call?
Thank you.

Comment: same issue facing here